# Clarification on a proof of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to proof the statement. Is this proof valid? I am not sure whether Step #4 is right or not. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

** Oh my bad, what I mean is: prove if S and T are sets then ...

[image]

Update answer:
[image]

Comment: You don't reverse the implications.

Comment: "$x \notin S \cap T$" in the second line implies "$x \notin S$ or $x \notin T$".

Comment: @E W H Lee oh, is it? I never know about that before.

Answer (score 1):

No, the move from the second line to the third line is invalid. More specifically:

$$(x\in T\cup S)\land (x\notin T\cap S)\iff(x\in T\lor x\in S)\land(x\notin T\lor x\notin S)$$
You replaced that last $\lor$ by $\land$, which is incorrect.

The move from the third to fourth line is also problematic, since you can't just omit parenthesis from $\lor$ into $\land$. This is a source for mistakes and difficulties in reading the proof.

Comment: yeah that's exactly what i am thinking. I was not sure whether the move from third to fourth line is valid

Comment: so, should I use the distributive law of logic in this case?

Comment: Yes, you should. You get four sub-clauses, some of which are outright impossible. The remaining two are the ones you are after. In either case you need to correct the third line as well, not just the fourth.

Comment: okay then I'll try it now!

Comment: do you mind to see my update answer? is the move from step 4 to step 5 is valid?

Comment: Yes, the edit is much better. I'd add another line between 4 and 5 explaining why you can omit the two clauses (HINT: it's like taking a union with the empty set, twice.)

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in (S\cup T)-(S\cap T)$.  Suppose $x\in S$; since $x\not\in S\cap T$, $x\not\in T$.  Therefore $x\in S - T$.  By symmetry, if $x\in T$ you can show $x\in T - S$.  This  yields
$$(S\cup T) - (S\cap T) \subseteq (S - T)\cup(T - S).$$
Can you conduct the converse argument in a similar fashion?